# Including perl modules

Tags: perl

I was wondering, do all of the modules I use in a perl script need to be at the beginning of the a script?

The reason I am wonder is I have a place in my script where it "splits" one way is the script connects with SSH using authorized keys. The other way is the script connects with SSH using a username and password. I am using the modules [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) to do SSH. According the cpan doc if I want all username and password authentication I need [IO::Pty](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IO%3a%3aPty).

Well I wanted to only check the requirement of [IO::Pty](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IO%3a%3aPty) if the subroutine set to login with username and password is triggered. Is that possible? To load the module only if a certain subroutine is triggered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `use IO::Pty;` line means the following to Perl:

```
BEGIN {
    require IO::Pty;
    IO::Pty->import;
}
```

So first Perl loads the module with require (which will die if it can't find the module), and then it calls the `->import` method if it exists.

You can turn this into a runtime conditional as follows:

```
 if (eval {require IO::Pty}) {
     # IO::Pty->import;
     # or use fully qualified names: IO::Pty::some_sub(...);
     # in both cases, the parenthesis after the subroutine are required, since
     # the import is not visible at compile time
 } else {
     # run other code, or throw an error with `die`
 }
```

Packages import into other packages, not into other scopes, so the import will be visible outside of the subroutine that performs it.  It is probably best to skip the import all together and just use fully qualified names.

Comment: Unless you import at `BEGIN` time, the compiler won’t have the right prototypes, and in fact won’t let you get away with using those functions as listops, either. A runtime import is of much more limited usefulness.

Comment: @tchrist - what exactly is a listop? Google seems to be pretty unhelpful on that term. I'm guessing you mean a function that allows sort/map -like syntax? Thanks

Comment: @DVK: No, I just mean not needing parens (which I always use anyway).

Comment: @tchrist - Ah. I am contemplating asking a question on whether there's EVER any point/benefit in omitting parenthesis

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to load a module *sometimes* then you can use require and eval to check whether you have it:

```
$haveit = eval "require Foo::Bar";
if ($haveit) {
   # do something
}
```

The 'use' routine actually does two things:

```
require Foo::Bar;
import Foo::Bar;
```

The thing is that 'use' does this at the beginning of the execution, not in a conditional place.  So don't use 'use' if you want to only load a module "sometimes" and instead use require and import where you actually want to.

**Edited to include: **

I should have referenced the perl ['use' documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) that explains this very well.

```
use Module;
```

is equivalent to:

```
BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }
```

And it's the "BEGIN" part that causes it to be loaded no matter where it is in the script, even in another if() clause.

Comment: Ah I see, but if I do `import Foo::Bar` in a subroutine does it only apply to the subroutine or does it apply to the entire script?

Comment: @Solignis, it imports into the current package.

Comment: ikegami is right: and the normal current package for the primary script would be 'main'.

Comment: I see, well this pretty much answer my question. Thanks guys.

Comment: Please remember that a runtime `require` followed by an `import` is not the same as a compile-time `use`, because often the compiler gets diddled a bit by the `import` and does things differently, whether because of prototypes seen or certain sorts of overloading. This is especially common with pragmas, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at [Module::Load](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/Module-Load-0.18/lib/Module/Load.pm).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to load IO::Pty yourself, Net::OpenSSH will load it when required.